# find a specific user/service account by UUID

Tags: azure, terraform, resources, uuid, federation

What I'm attempting: Use Terraform automate SAML relations between Azure <> Okta <> AWS.

What I'm missing: any sort of formal education on Azure; pure noob.

I've followed the Okta docs and performed those steps (for an Enterprise Application) manually; they worked perfectly.

I'm nearing the end of terraforming the solution but hung up on one thing. The EA that was created manually has this block:

```
resource "azuread_application" "test" {
  ...
  oauth2_permission_scope_ids    = {
      "user_impersonation" = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
```

The Terraformed instance of the EA is missing this parameter/value. It was created for me when doing the steps manually in the UI - but with Terraforming, I'm responsible for creating it. It's necessary but I can't seem to find out where it comes from. Also, this UUID shows up in these places as well:

```
resource "azuread_application" "test" {
  oauth2_permission_scope_ids    = {
      "user_impersonation" = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  ...
  api {
  ...
    oauth2_permission_scope {
    ...
      id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "test" {
  ...
  oauth2_permission_scope_ids = {
    "user_impersonation" = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
  ...
  oauth2_permission_scopes = [
    {
    ...
      id  = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

***How would one go about finding a specific resource in Azure using only a UUID?***

Or, maybe someone knows which resource needs to be terraformed?

Either/both answers would be welcome, TIA.

Comment: UPDATE: the above UUID is auto-generated by assigning an Okta value to an Azure Application scopes value. In Azure, navigate to: AAD > App registrations (All applications): Select the App in question. In the left nav click: Expose API and configure the assignment. The above UUID is automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

> How would one go about finding a specific resource in Azure using only a UUID?

For built-in scopes, you have to use the default ID.

**Azure Active Directory > App registration > API Permission**

[image]

The below **Terraform** code will create the **Azure AD Application** with custom scope with random **UUID**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "random_uuid" "test" {
}

resource "azuread_application" "sampleapplication5" {
  display_name     = "demoapp2"

  api {
    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description  = "sample application"
      admin_consent_display_name = "sample"
      enabled                    = true
      id                         = random_uuid.test.id
      type                       = "User"
      value                      = "accessasuser"
    }
  }
  }
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once ran the above code scope is added to application successfully.

[image]

Reference: [Resource: azuread_application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application)

Comment: I tried this out; Terraform totally gave me a `UUID` but it wasn't useful in the other fields (mentioned above). That particular `UUID` would have to come from some resource that can (in the case of `user_impersonation`) do a thing on a users behalf. Seems like that would be a service account of some sort? The hunt continues.